# Node js Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

Please help me to understand these statements.

What does `.expect` and `.Api('api')` mean here?

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var Api = Bluecat.Api('api');
```

Comment: You can look up the documentation for `chai` here: http://chaijs.com/. You'll find the documentation for `Bluecat` here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluecat

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a poor question for this platform as it can be answered with sufficient research on your part.

Comment: Why not consult the documentation first?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With that line of code, you assign chai's expect-function to your expect variable.

[Here](http://chaijs.com/) you can find what you can do with expect.

Answer (score -2):

`require` returns an object representing the module you've just loaded. `.expect` and `.Api` are properties defined within each respective module. `Api` in this case is a function/method, and the code here doesn't tell us what `expect` is, but naming conventions suggest it'll be a function too.